# Wanting my page to resize with no east-to-west scroll

Tags: css, responsive-design, image-resizing

I have a page and I want to eliminate the scenario where it scrolls left to right. No matter what resolution I view it on, it leaves about 70px of white-space on the right. On the page http://bitfilmfund.com/ I have set

for the city image background part, I have already set the body to be:

```
    #baner {
    min-width: 100%;
    float: left;
    background: url(../images/city-backgound.jpg);
    margin-top: 0px;
    }

    html {
    margin: 0px;
    min-height: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
    }

    body {
    margin: 0px;
    min-height: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
    }
```

I also did a media query where I defined the CSS to resize the image based on a max-width of the viewport, such as:
       @media (max-width: 1600px) {
       #baner {width: 100%;
       }
       }
to get the city scape image to stretch the screen, and tried smaller sizes too for smaller res's, but it just does not work.

There is consistently a patch of white space at the right. Even if I set the CSS width's to be as high (high number for width, that is) as they can be until the screen is filled, I still have the left-right scroll. I want the images and background to resize to fill the screen and create no need for left-right scroll. Why don't this CSS works?

Comment: Tip: You can use `html, body {}` instead of repeating the whole set of rules.

Comment: I did that to no avail. I did html {
   margin: 0px;
   min-height: 100%;
   min-width: 100%;
}

body {
   margin: 0px;
   min-height: 100%;
   min-width: 100%;
}

Answer (score 2):

### Quick Fix:

The first `<div>` with  `class='row'` is causing the page to scroll horizontally; more specifically:

```
margin-left: -15px;
margin-right: -15px;
```

will cause this unwanted whitespace and horizontal scrollbar.

Additionally, the margin on the `<body>` should be set as:

```
margin: 0px;
```

in order to avoid some browsers (Chrome, for example) applying the 'default' margin that they like to apply.

### Longer (surplus) fix:

Whilst the container elements on the page are re-sizing dynamically, a fair amount of the content is not. (Including the banner image as mentioned and the iframe containing the video.) The user's viewport size should be taken into consideration, in that when viewed from a smaller ~<1675px width the top navigation bar refuses to resize down and instead creates the horizontal scrolling issue. These problems can be fixed by using percentages rather than px, as I am sure you are well aware, (considering the usage of percentages on container elements).

Obviously, the screen size cannot resize down indefinitely - a limit has to be drawn somewhere. According to [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_display.asp), most browsers are now above the 1024x768px as a minimum, even [Google](https://www.google.co.uk/?gws_rd=ssl) doesn't resize down to this level however. It's up to you to choose where the minimum size lies for your website; but the more all-encompassing, the better.

### Banner image:

This should be a fairly straightforward part, the following CSS properties should be of use to you, when added with the CSS that defines the image to be displayed:

```
background-size: 100%;
background: //your-image-location// no-repeat;
```

This will however, become stretched or compressed depending on the browser size, but is a good starting point for resolving the issue.

Comment: hey thanks. I'm going to digest this info. Many Thanks. Like I said, I'm trying to get my skills sharper.

Comment: No problem my friend, I hope it's of some use - don't hesitate to ask if you need more from me!

Comment: hey MANY thanks! I did those things but it still wasn't taking away the white space at the right, but was definitely resetting SOME stuff. So I combed through the stuff I wrote on there and adjusted things in inspect-element here and there until I found the culprit - the margin that I set on the video player div ( #mdlvdo_a ), took away the margin and now I'm good. I just have to restyle stuff and be more careful about margins and things. Thanks again.

Comment: I'm usually good when I have to write the code myself from scratch, but as of late I have been inheriting broken pages and problematic pages for work that I have to de-bug or fix, and it's often hard for me to go in and fix problematic code that I'm unfamiliar with.

Comment: Good to hear it's all sorted for you, happy internetting! :)